# Is there a canonical way to format 'usage' output for a cli script?

Tags: python, cli

I have a python script that is supposed to be used as a small cli program.
[This](https://developers.google.com/style/code-syntax) is google's recommendations on how to document cli syntax. I was wondering, are there similar recommendations, or specifications, perhaps from GNU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*In the Python world*, by far the most common is "do what `argparse` does". The reasons for this are hopefully obvious.

Comment: This will get a new projected started very fast on the right foot: import [typer](https://pypi.org/project/typer), `def main(...` with type [annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), then finally `typer.run(main)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a [GNU Standard](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html#:%7E:text=All%20programs%20should%20support%20two,same%20information%20as%20invoking%20%27%20p.) which is slightly more than to follow the [POSIX Standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), which is used by a great number of programs and a good template to follow.

There is a style for Windows, but it is wretched so I'm not going to cite it, don't use it, stick to above.

In the specific case of python, follow the accepted answer.